# how to make secure connection with phonegap desktop

Tags: javascript, https, geolocation, phonegap

I need to make secure connection,**https://192.168.42.253:3000/#/map/home** instead of **http://192.168.42.253:3000/#/map/home**, I am using phonegap desktop cli.

[image]

because " navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(succes,error,timeout)" to get current loation using js is  not working in http.

Comment: Have you looked into the geolocation plugin? https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/

Comment: @evolutionxbox no issue with phone build, i am getting lat,lon using geolocation..but In phone I cant able to naviagate to current location, I want to debug it that is why I need https connection.I am using this map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions); to navigate.

Comment: Looking at the CLI (which the desktop app uses) it doesn't offer a HTTPS option https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/blob/master/doc/cli/help.serve.txt